# Ошибка при объявлении 2 байт в stack segment

Tags: ассемблер, dos

Следующий код собирается без ошибок, но при попытке выполнения команды MOV AX,STCKSG программа завершается с ошибкой.

```
STCKSG SEGMENT STACK
       DB 2 DUP(55H)
STCKSG ENDS
CODSEG SEGMENT
       ASSUME CS:CODSEG,SS:STCKSG
BEGIN:
       MOV AX,STCKSG
       MOV SS,AX
       MOV AH,4CH
       INT 21H
CODSEG ENDS
       END BEGIN
```

[image: ОшибкаПриВыполнении]

Если же вместо DB 2 DUP(55H) написать, например, DB 30 DUP('*'), то все работает. В чем может быть причина ошибки?

Убрал строки: MOV AH,4CH и INT 21H. Программа завершается с ошибкой при попытке выполнить команду MOV AX,STCKSG. Если в стеке не определять вообще никаких байт, даже если есть прерывание INT 21H программа работает и завершается без ошибок.

Comment: Может ваш отладчик врет ? Что то мне подсказывает, что отладчик вполне может ошибаться в ситуации переполнения стека. А стек из 2х байт конечно переполнится например при выполнении int 21h, потому как int надо положить минимум 6 байт в стек

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можете посоветовать качественных материалов по изучению ассемблера? Начинал с книги Питер Абель Ассемблер и программирование для IBM PC, но обнаружил в ней много ошибок и неточностей, поэтому переключился на книгу Пирогова. В ней примеров много, но разбора команд почти нет. Хотелось бы что бы подробно и последовательно разъяснялась каждая команда, которую я буду использовать. В любом случае, спасибо! :)

Comment: Ну я с Абеля начинал. Потом был справочник по архитектуре 80486. В любом случае надо брать что то более современное. Потому что современные процессоры могут на порядок больше того, что описано в книгах 25 летней давности. И изучать сейчас что то про те же прерывания DOS вообще смысла не имеет, потому что они нигде не применяются. У современных ОС другие интерфейсы.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду пытаться :)

Comment: Убрал строки: MOV AH,4CH и INT 21H. Программа завершается с ошибкой при попытке выполнить команду MOV AX,STCKSG. Если в стеке не определять вообще никаких байт, даже если есть прерывание INT 21H программа работает и завершается без ошибок.

Comment: @Николай, не экономьте на стеке. При срабатывании любого фонового прерывания (например, прерывания таймера, которое срабатывает само, независимо от действий пользователя) весь контекст выполнения (все регистры, например) сохраняются в стек. При занесении в стек больше чем 2 байт скорее всего начнут затираться данные, расположенные в памяти выше него. Возможно причина в этом (но это не точно).

Comment: @insolor Я считал, что нужно выделять в стеке столько памяти, сколько потребуется для выполнения инструкций в программе. Отсюда и ошибка. Спасибо :)